# .net core web api responding with 500 when published to azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I deployed my .net core web api to azure and now it responds with 500 whenever i make a request to it.
It uses entity framework with the database also deployed on azure. It works perfectly fine on localhost iis express. Here is my appsetings.json. I have changed the connection string for security reasons, it actually has real values in it. How can i get more information about this error or how can i solve it?

````
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionString": {
    "prodSchoolProjectDB": "Server={serverName},1433;Initial Catalog=SchoolProjectDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={databaseId};Password={databasePassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going into firewall settings of my database which is deployed on azure and activated the permission of azure services.

Answer (score 1):

For start, you can go enable "App Service logs" blade under Monitoring section and enable "Application Logging (Filesystem)", then go to "Log stream". While you have the logs, send another request or just restart your app. You should be able to see more details.

Comment: i enabled it and went to log stream and i don't get any logs.

Comment: Did you restart the app while log is enabled?

Comment: IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.

Comment: Do you have the internal error message?
I'm suggesting to keep the log stream open, and in another tab restart the app while the log screen is open. this way you wont lose any message.